# Lost panel transparency and gain 2 more workspaces after installing tight vnc server

Tags: xubuntu, xfce-panel

Last day I have installed tight vnc server on my PC. After reboot my window-decoration options were changed, two more workspaces were added and xfce-panels went solid color (previously they were transparent). The problem is that I cannot change my panels to be transparent - this option is no longer available. Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Same problem here,
i log in XFCE session, when i turn back xubuntu session. Transparency gone.. 2 more workspaces... And on panel appearance tab, i can't see alpha slider anymore..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Enabling compositing in window manager tweaks solved the problem.